# TypeWriter font have no effect with polyglossia package

Tags: xetex, fontspec, polyglossia, fancyvrb, ucharclasses

Using XeLaTeX engine, MWE1 works fine with fontspec and ucharclasses package. But when I change fontspec to polyglossia (MWE2), there is no TypeWriter font effect. Moreover, the first sentence of English text is not in Times New Roman font. Is there any fix?

MWE1

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\khmerfont[Script=Khmer,Scale=0.9]{Khmer OS}
\newfontfamily\khmerfonttt[Script=Khmer,Scale=0.9]{Khmer OS}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Computer Modern Roman}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\khmerfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\englishfont}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\noindent What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក? What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក?
\begin{Verbatim}
What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក? What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក?
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

MWE2

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\khmerfont[Script=Khmer,Scale=0.9]{Khmer OS}
\newfontfamily\khmerfonttt[Script=Khmer,Scale=0.9]{Khmer OS}
\newfontfamily\englishfont{Computer Modern Roman}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=khmer]{khmer}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{Khmer}{\khmerfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{\englishfont}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\noindent What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក? What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក?
\begin{Verbatim}
What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក? What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក?
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

Khmer OS font http://www.khmeros.info/en/fonts

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: @samcarter: I am using TeXlive 2016 on window 7 operating system. Whenever I run the answer code, it still produce an error as pointed out in comment.

Answer (score 2):

I get wrong output in both cases. At least in the english text they are more font family involved so you need a bit more sophisticated font changing. Try this instead:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\newfontfamily\khmerfont[Script=Khmer,Scale=0.9]{Khmer OS}
\setdefaultlanguage[numerals=khmer]{khmer}
\setotherlanguage{english}
\usepackage{ucharclasses}
\makeatletter
\setTransitionTo{Khmer}{%
 \global\let\orif@family\f@family
 \khmerfont}
\setTransitionFrom{Khmer}{%
 \fontfamily{\orif@family}\selectfont}
 \makeatother
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\begin{document}
\noindent What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក ? What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក?
\begin{Verbatim}
What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក? What is wrong? តើមានអ្វីប្លែក?
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

If you have a dedicated tt-font for khmer you could add some test for the current family.

[image]

Comment: Yes, you are right. Both MWE produce wrong output! However, your suggestion work only for MWE1. So I think the the polyglossia command \setdefaultlanguage cause this issue.

Comment: @SayOL: I don't know what you mean. My example uses polyglossia and produces the output in the picture. What is wrong with it?

Comment: I still encountered error **Package polyglossia Error: Please define \khmerfont with \newfontfamily.^^I\begin{Verbatim}**

Comment: And the normal English text is not in Computer Modern Roman

Comment: I don't get errors in a current texlive. And for the font  you can probably use `\setmainfont{CMU Serif}` but  the default Latin Modern looks quite similar.